# Sign Up with Devise on Heroku goes to a status=500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I have been trying to troubleshoot this all day I can't get it figured out. I have devise working on development, but when I push to Heroku it doesn't work.

When I first push the code, the site will load and I can see the homepage. When I click the login link, I am able to go to the /users/sign_up page.

Once I enter in the user details and hit submit I get a page that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong." on the root URL.

When I look in heroku console, the user was created. When I delete the user in the console, I can load the homepage again..

When I tail the logs I get the following:

```
    2015-01-14T03:08:35.973477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=herokuapp.com request_id=cd15706e-1dcf-4423-9f29-551f47b86cc3 fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=77ms status=304 bytes=732
2015-01-14T03:08:36.139198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1dc4981637a32fd174590c5f8e6c740a.css" host=herokuapp.com request_id=4a355fa8-1792-455f-9d7c-4af22b3592dc fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-14T03:08:36.169634+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6d9ad2cbcb5603db021e610fea035881.js" host=herokuapp.com request_id=5907fef4-e1dd-4fe8-a3e8-0741d66b0675 fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-14T03:08:36.677241+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokuapp.com request_id=7f01792c-9cad-4010-89c8-0dd632b99c34 fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=17ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-14T03:14:31.571097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6d9ad2cbcb5603db021e610fea035881.js" host=.herokuapp.com request_id=e6fd320f-bb55-41eb-8b7b-d86f9b686a7f fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-14T03:14:31.393836+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=herokuapp.com request_id=c58f55fb-93c9-45f5-8729-8732d5447c8b fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=44ms status=304 bytes=732
2015-01-14T03:14:31.569124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1dc4981637a32fd174590c5f8e6c740a.css" host=herokuapp.com request_id=bf530876-0d84-4b94-a0c2-f454b2dcfd99 fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-14T03:14:31.822101+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokuapp.com request_id=c647088e-a020-4fae-96c2-902a5c04de3d fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-14T03:16:05.917921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_up" host=herokuapp.com request_id=bdb7264e-cf0a-470d-849f-0456b21fdfc5 fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=4637
2015-01-14T03:16:20.955668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=herokuapp.com request_id=19bf8082-f7fb-49bf-872c-54e31dee72cf fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=182ms status=302 bytes=1192
2015-01-14T03:16:21.090669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=herokuapp.com request_id=8741d387-1953-4f7d-ace8-48736db9a500 fwd="99.19.1.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

I have done heroku rake db:migrate a million times.

What else can I do to try to and figure out what is going on?

I also disabled devise :confirmable for the time being.

ruby '2.1.5'
rails '4.1.8'
devise 3.4.1
cancancan 1.9.2

Any of this help?

```
2015-01-14T04:09:45.064882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-01-14T04:09:46.978100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441918+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441912+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-14 04:09:47] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441940+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441942+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441946+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441947+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441944+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441954+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441960+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441955+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441950+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441949+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441957+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.481089+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:21786
2015-01-14T04:09:47.481093+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-01-14T04:09:47.481095+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-01-14T04:09:47.481096+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-01-14T04:09:47.481084+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441958+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441966+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-14 04:09:47] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441952+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-01-14T04:09:47.441968+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-14 04:09:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-01-14T04:09:47.481091+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-01-14T04:09:48.198859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-01-14T04:09:50.097709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 24511 -e production`
2015-01-14T04:09:54.054846+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-14 04:09:54] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-01-14T04:09:54.054823+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-14 04:09:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-01-14T04:09:54.055225+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-14 04:09:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=24511
2015-01-14T04:09:54.626003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: Set the development environment to heroku and see the stack trace of error.

Comment: Which version of devise, ruby etc are you using?

Comment: @Masud how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @heading_to_tahiti I added the version numbers. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: `heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: @Masudul found this a million years later, saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Since your User is being created this leads me to believe that devise may be working properly and that the error is in fact within the code for your root view.  Double check that you are not trying to call an attribute from the User that is not assigned yet.  For example in most applications on the homepage after you log in you may have a message at the top that says "Welcome back Jim", well if you did not create the User object with the "first_name" attribute it is set to nil and interpolating that string with a nil value will throw a 500 error.

You might have missed throwing this error in development due to the evolution of your code, by assigning a value to the attribute causing the problem, before writing the code that is throwing the error on the root view.

**Double check your code for any attributes of the User that are being called by the root page which were not assigned when the User was created.**

Comment: Yeah, when I delete the User from the heroku console and reload the page I get "Welcome! You have signed up successfully." in the alerts/notices section of the site. So devise seems to be working. I will edit the root URL attributes and report back. Thanks

Comment: still no luck, I removed all the content from the homepage and just went to the /users/sign_up url. Once I signed up, I still get a status 500 for the "/" path

Comment: Ok, check your controller as well for any attribute of the User that is possibly being called and expected to be not nil.

Comment: I'm using @user = current_user in the controller and in the root view I am using <% if user_signed_in? %>. I added the code explained here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user for the guest user.

Comment: What attributes of User are you assigning when the use performs the signup action?  In your development environment go into rails console and destroy the User you have been using.  And create the fresh User through the sign_up action.  If you get 500 error there than I am right, the User you were using in dev had an extra attribute that was assigned before the problem code was put into place through your evolution of the development.  If you don't get 500 than we will move onto other possibilities.

Comment: Yeah I did that while trying to test. I deleted all the data from my tables to start fresh (like in production). In the console I ran User.count and it returned 0. I was able to sign up a new user on development without any problems...

Comment: Do all views fail with 500 after login or just the root?

Comment: Looks like it is just the pages that display User data. I can go to static pages, but when I go to any page that relates or pulls user data to the user I get 500 errors. FYI, in my index controller I change '@'user = current_user to '@'user = current_or_guest_user to make it automatically create a guest user. It works on dev but it failed on production.

Comment: Ok let's get more information from the Heroku logs as to what's failing.  Access your heroku app and perform the failing operation then run heroku logs -n 3000 to get a larger chunk of the logs.  Then store it in a doc off SO and paste the link here so I can take a look.  The log snippet you pasted above does not provide much help.

Comment: I think I have it narrowed down. The problem is the way I am calling a model method in the view. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Calling a model method in the view?  What was your solution to solve this?